# Using celery to asynchronously perform a task for a Django app

Tags: django, django-models, redis, django-views, celery

In a Django app I maintain, users log in and exchange messages with one another, forum style. At any given point in time, I show who's online, by checking whoever logged a `session` object within the last 5 mins. To accomplish that, I use the Django plugin [user_sessions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-user-sessions), that allows manipulating sessions like regular ORM.

My code to accomplish this is thus:

```
class WhoseOnlineView(ListView):
    model = Session
    template_name = "whose_online.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        unique_user_sessions = Session.objects.filter(last_activity__gte=(timezone.now()-timedelta(minutes=5))).only('user').distinct('user')
        users = [session.user for session in unique_user_sessions]
        users = [user for user in users if user is not None] #sanitizing None values
        return users
```

---

The website's users (and features) have grown considerably, and as per newrelic, this particular view is consuming the most amount of time among all my views.

I'm thinking I should move this entire task to be accomplished asynchronously. I have celery (with redis as message broker) up and running under supervisord on my production server.

This could be a periodic task, carried out once every 60 seconds. But it seems that for that to work, I'd need to **save the results** in the DB (or cache), so that users can see the saved results till the next time the whose online list is processed.

Can someone please give me an illustrative example on how to accomplish this? The main thing that I'm struggling with is how to save (or cache) the results that are then displayed to users, before the next periodic task is kicked off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

First, to write the celery task to figure out the logged in users, e.g.

```
# fooapp.tasks

@shared_task
def whoseonline(): 
    unique_user_sessions = Session.objects.filter(last_activity__gte=(timezone.now()-timedelta(minutes=5))).only('user').distinct('user')
    users = [session.user for session in unique_user_sessions        users = [user for user in users if user is not None] #sanitizing None values
    # save the users to the cache
    cache.set('online_users', users, 70)  # expiring in 70 seconds
```

and set the task up so that run certain amount of time, e.g. 60 seconds, adding this:

```
# settings.py

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'whoseonline': {
        'task': 'fooapp.tasks.whoseonline',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=60),  # execute every 60 seconds
        'args': (),
    },
}
```

to your settings. Then, in your view, you just need to do

```
class WhoseOnlineView(ListView):
    model = Session
    template_name = "whose_online.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        # take the values from the cache
        return cache.get('online_users')
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/) more about cache and [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) more about celery.

You also should take in mind, that cache time expiration (70 sec in the sample) should be greater than scheduled time you will use for the celery task (60 sec in the sample), so that the view always has something to show.

Comment: Hmm, the cache backend I'm using is `django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache`. It seems everything works as expected, except I can't set or get cache correctly. Is there any way to test whether cache is being correct set? I tried `django debug toolbar`, and as per that, cache isn't being called.

Comment: You should take a look to the link i passed to you, about cache. You can find there how to set up all the cache machinery and how to use it

Comment: That's precisely what I'm using. To be exact, this part: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching That's a very no-nonsense setup, so I'm kind of stumped what I'm missing.

Comment: I've been diagnosing it, I'm getting 'None' when trying to `get` the stored result in the view. Strangely, `get` in tasks.py (right after `set`) works perfectly fine. Strange.

Comment: Be sure to use the same key in both sides and the time is enough to be always available.